# illumina`s barcode.fastq contains lots of distinct sequences

Tags: python, algorithm, bioinformatics

I am a little confused about my MiSeq v2 sequencing results. I`ve been using six distinct barcodes to distinguish my samples but for some reasons the "barcode" file contains more than 70k distinct sequences. So I guess this kind of situation can happen due to errors, occurred while reading barcodes. How can I handle this ambiguity? Currently I am trying to use custom Python script, which tries to clusterise barcodes by Levenhstein distance from each other (and from templates I have chosen).

Comment: Perhaps these sequences overlap somehow? Patchwork seems likely considering the number of sequences is far greater than your number of chromosomes, mitochondrial or otherwise. Did you consult with the sequencing service provider?

Comment: For bioinformatics-related questions, also consider posting on more specific Q&A sites like https://www.biostars.org/ or http://seqanswers.com/